# ggplot x axis label containing subscript and other characters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to label the x-axis of a volcano plot I made using EnhancedVolcano as "Log2(B/A)" where 2 is a subscript, and B/A is a character vector I define as X.axis. Xlab is one of the arguments of EnhancedVolcano function.

I tried:

```
X.axis <- "(B/A)"
log2 <- expression(~Log[2])
xlab = paste(log2,X.axis)
```

Result was `~Log[2](B/A)`

I also tried:

```
log2 <- expression(~Log[2]~X.axis)
xlab = log2
```

This gave `Log2 X.axis`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not think there is a `paste` function that is designed to accept multiple expression classed arguments. There is a plotmath `paste` function that that just deals with literals. Furthermore the "~" symbol gets handled differently inside expression. In that context it's just a space-character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put "Log2(X.axis)" as an x axis label where "X.axis" is dynamically defined as an argument of a function and 2 is a subscript:

```
plot <- function(df, X.axis){  
X.axis <- rlang::enexpr(X.axis)  
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = bquote( ~ Log[2] ~ (.(X.axis))))
}
```

To use with EnhancedVolcano package, you can simply add `+ labs(x = bquote( ~ Log[2] ~ (.(X.axis))))` after `EnhancedVolcano(x)`

Answer (score 1):

```r
X.axis <- "B/A"
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = bquote(Log[2] * bgroup("(", .(X.axis), ")" )))
```

[image: ggplot with bquote axis label]

Alternatively, you can do a more-apparent fraction, though it is easier (given what little I know of your available variables) to do it statically:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = bquote(Log[2] * bgroup("(", over(B, A), ")" )))
```

[image]

I admit to not knowing all of the differences between using `expression(.)` and `bquote(.)` for labels and such. They return different class objects (`expression` and `call`, respectively) but can be used interchangeably in many cases, but the latter supports (for instance) value replacement (the `.(X.axis)` above), something I find very useful.

Comment: I  think some sort of natural language  commentary on why `bquote` was chosen (for well and good reasons) and why "*" was used instead of "~" would have made the answer up-worthy.

Comment: Short of reading the help pages again and do more research to answer *your* question @IRTFM, I personally do not know from memory what the key differences are. Can you please inform us? (I'll upvote your comment ;-)

Comment: And yes that would certainly add value ... I ran out of time and preferred to post it as is. Perhaps I'll come back later to at content.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of my comments to r2evans:

The advantage of `bquote` over `expression` is that its embedded, accessory function cryptically named `"."` allows one to access values of named objects that exist in the calling frame. The `expression` function never evaluates the symbols or tokens that are placed in its list of arguments. The disadvantage of `bquote` is that it will not accept multiple arguments. To return multiple arguments as an expression list/vector with `bquote`, one needs to deploy it with an `sapply` or `lapply` call.

The `bquote`with`.` function-combo solved the puzzle that was facing the OP who wanted the value of `X.axis` but instead only got its name in the printed  result of the `expression` call. Keeping the various levels of meaning straight is a challenge to new users of R. The introduction of the `tidyverse` solved that challenge in some settings by collapsing the layers to some extent, but probably delays acquisition of understanding ordinary "standard evaluation" in R.

The tilde operator inside an argument to `expression` is handled by the plotmath engine as a space. Notice that r2evans did not use a tilde but rather used an asterisk "*", because it is also a valid separator to delimit the tokenization process by the R parser, but it leaves no "space" in the plotmath output. The `tilde operator has many, diverse uses in R. It can be a function returning a formula, a spacing operator in a plotmath expression or a couple of different  connector un a tidyverse evaluation